# Django, searching with custom QuerySet, erroneously returning empty object

Tags: python, django

forgive me if this has been answered before, I have searched Stackover flow and I haven't seen any questions/answers that my problem
If you know one that matches please point me there

I have a Django project set up (version 1.11)
Along with Python 3.5.3
I have an app called Product and I wish to search its database
its model.py looks like this:

```
import random
import os
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from .utils import unique_slug_generator


def get_filename_ext(filepath):
    base_name = os.path.basename(filepath)
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(base_name)
    return name, ext

def upload_image_path(instance, filename):
    new_filename = random.randint(1, 1000000)
    name, ext = get_filename_ext(filename)
    final_filename = '{new_filename}{ext}'.format(new_filename=new_filename, ext=ext)
    return "products/{new_filename}/{final_filename}".format(
            new_filename=new_filename,
            final_filename=final_filename
            )


class ProductQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def active(self):
        return self.filter(featured=True, active=True)

    def featured(self):
        return self.filter(featured=True)

    def search(self, query):
        lookups = (Q(title__icontains=query) |
                   Q(description__icontains=query)|
                   Q(price__icontains=query))
        result = self.filter(lookups).distinct()
        print(result)
        return self.filter(lookups).distinct()


class ProductManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return ProductQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def all(self):
        return self.get_queryset()

    def featured(self):
        return self.get_queryset().featured()

    def get_by_id(self, id):
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(id=id) # Product.object
        if qs.count() ==1:
            return qs.first()
        return None

    def search(self, query):
        return self.get_queryset().active().search(query)



class Product(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug            = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    description     = models.TextField()
    price           = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, default=39.99)
    image           = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/', null=True, blank=True)
    featured        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active          = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = ProductManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("products:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.title


def product_pre_save_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = unique_slug_generator(instance)

pre_save.connect(product_pre_save_receiver, sender=Product)
```

I have a search app which facilitates this search.
its view.py looks like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView
from products.models import Product

class SearchProductView(ListView):
    template_name="search/view.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchProductView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        context['query'] = query
        # SearchQuery.objects.create(query=query)
        return context

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = self.request
        method_dict = request.GET
        query = method_dict.get('q', None) # method_dict['q']
        if query is not None:
             return Product.objects.search(query)
        return Product.objects.featured()
```

the situation is that in when I pass the value "Hat" to - def get_queryset() in Views.py
I receive an empty object. I know there is an entry in the data base called "hat"

it is only when I move the following code from ProductQuerySet:

```
lookups = (Q(title__icontains=query) |
                   Q(description__icontains=query)|
                   Q(price__icontains=query))
        result = self.filter(lookups).distinct()
```

to replace

```
return Product.objects.search(query)
```

that i get a result.

Any ideas as to why the code at the top is returning an empty object?

Comment: Should the active method also filter by featured being true?

Comment: not all products will be featured, I tried adding Active=True and Featured=True. Sadly no joy

Comment: No, I mean in `ProductQuerySet.active` you filter by both active and featured being true. You probably didn't mean this?

Comment: sorry my bad, I have removed it :)

Comment: it has worked, now when i run, get_queryset().active().search(query). I get a result

Comment: please put it as an answer so you can get some reputation for it. ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The active method should only filter by active being true and not on features being true

```
class ProductQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def active(self):
        return self.filter(active=True)
```